# Android arrrayOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from the Arraylist I use.Whenever I try to click back button when i am at 1st item of arraylist or the next button when i am at the last item of arraylist my app crash.And for the rest of the items it works perfectly on next and previous button click.I don't know exactly how to check when the index is out of reach.

1.Here is my : Activity Class

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 int position=0;
ImageButton buttonNext;
ImageButton buttonPrevious;
ImageButton buttonPlay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
   final TextView nameEnglish =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.engNames);
   final TextView arabicTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.araName);
   final TextView txtMeaning =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textMeaning);



    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final List<Names> namesList= bundle.getParcelableArrayList("LIST");
     position = bundle.getInt("Position");
  final   Names mk = namesList.get(position);

    if (bundle != null) {


        nameEnglish.setText(mk.getName());
        arabicTxt.setText(mk.getArabicName());
        txtMeaning.setText(mk.getMeaning());
    }
    buttonNext=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);
    buttonPrevious = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);
    buttonPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.playbutton);

    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (position==namesList.size()-1)
            {

                buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
            }
            position++;
            Names names1 = namesList.get(position);

            if (position < namesList.size() ){

                nameEnglish.setText(names1.getName());
                arabicTxt.setText(names1.getArabicName());
                txtMeaning.setText(names1.getMeaning());


            }



        }
    });

    buttonPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (position == 0) {

                buttonPrevious.setEnabled(false);
            }

            position--;
            Names names2 = namesList.get(position);


            if (position > 0 ) {

                nameEnglish.setText(names2.getName());
                arabicTxt.setText(names2.getArabicName());
                txtMeaning.setText(names2.getMeaning());



            }

        }
    });


}
```

}

3.**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.islamiclearn.namesofallah, PID: 18205
                                                                           java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=99; index=-1
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:413)
                                                                               at com.islamiclearn.namesofallah.activity.SecondActivity$2.onClick(SecondActivity.java:85)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Thanks for yours advise in advance.

Comment: "I am new to the coding": one of the most important skills of a programmer is debugging a program. Carefully read error messages (in this case the exception tells you the index -1 and the line number where it happens) and use a debugger to step through the program in order to find the place where the actual behaviour deviates from your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (position==namesList.size()-1) {
    buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Will disable the button, but only for the next time it is pressed. The code afterwards will still run, with an invalid index.

```
position++;
Names names1 = namesList.get(position);

if (position < namesList.size() ){
    nameEnglish.setText(names1.getName());
    arabicTxt.setText(names1.getArabicName());
    txtMeaning.setText(names1.getMeaning());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=99; **index=-1**

Index `-1` is invalid so you must ensure you use the correct value to get stuff from the array.

Comment: i already make check on that but its not working i cant understand what 's the problem persisting on